# How should I find the line of best fit for a possible logarithmic scatter plot?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn

This is the first time I am giving a go with scikit learn. However, I am struggling to get the closest line of best fit using the following data

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]

y = [0, 187, 262, 296, 319, 340, 359, 376, 388, 401, 411, 414, 423, 430, 433, 439, 446, 452, 457, 461, 465, 469, 470, 470, 472, 474, 479, 484, 486, 487, 489, 489, 491, 491, 491, 494, 494, 498, 500, 500, 500, 500, 505, 506, 506, 506, 506, 507, 508, 509, 509, 509, 511, 511, 512, 514, 515, 515, 515, 517, 517, 518, 518, 518, 518, 518, 518, 518, 518, 518, 518, 518, 518, 518, 518, 518, 518, 518, 518, 518, 518, 518, 518, 518, 518, 519, 519, 519, 519, 519, 519, 519, 519, 519, 519, 519, 519, 519, 519, 519, 519]
```

I was able to graph the following out of of matplotlib...

[image]

...as a result of the code below...

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,8))
ax1 = plt.scatter(x, y, c = 'brown')

def func(x, a, b,c):
    return a*np.log2(b+x)+c

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, frequency['pct'], frequency['Facility Count Military'])

print(popt)
#popt was the following: [4.28209689e+01 1.46600585e-02 2.59467635e+02]

ax2 = sns.lineplot(frequency['pct'], popt[0]*np.log2(popt[1]+frequency['pct'])+popt[2], c = 'black')

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.ylim([0, 530])
plt.xlim([0, 100])
plt.title('y over x', y = 1, fontsize=15, fontweight='semibold')
plt.show()
```

(a) Is my methodology correct?
(b) Does it make sense to make a line of best fit with a log based 2 line or is this something different?

**Edited:**

Nevermind about part c. I just edited the code accordingly and figured that out on my own.

(c) Is there a way to translate the "popt" into the line graph that will eventually be used?

Any assistance on this is truly appreciated.

Comment: (a) Correct with respect to what goal? 
(b) Regarding the log base: you can use any base you want it is just a scale from natural log. If that's the "best" function to use, again I think it depends upon your objective. Have you tried anything else?

Comment: So basically, my goal is to get the closest line of best fit so that it stays much closer to every dot than what I have made previously.